# Have to update manually a view to see a dynamically created img in Internet Explorer. JQuery, ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

When I add an image, view is updated asynchronously and  the image is shown. However, if I try to add another image, then the previous image should be removed and new img tag with new image should be appended to imageBox3 div instead. Here is my JS code to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                 datatype: 'json',
                 url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
                  autoUpload: true,
                  done: function(e, data){
     if(data.result.sourceimg!="" &&     
     ($"#imageDivT").length!=0)){
     var toRemove=document.getElementById("imageElem");
    document.getElementById("imageBox3").removeChild(toRemove);
  }

  if(data.result.sourceimg!="" & ($("#imageDivT").
  length==0)){
  var img=document.createElement('img');
  img.src=data.result.sourceimg;
  img.id="imageElem";
  document.getElementById("imageBox3").appendchild(img);
  }});
```

It works in Opera browser,  but IE cannot render new image( I should press F5 to see new image). What is my error? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: what version of IE were you using?

Comment: @Roman Internet Explorer11